# Why did the system display an warning information when I use AudioManager?

Tags: android

The following code display an warning  information "The static field Context.AUDIO_SERVICE should be accessed in a static way", why? how to fix it? thanks!

```
public class CallerMain extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.caller_main);

        findViewById(R.id.btnEnableCall).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().AUDIO_SERVICE);
                int max = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume( AudioManager.STREAM_RING );
                mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, max, 0);

            }
        });     
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AUDIO_SERVICE` is the static variable in `Context` class

you should call like this

```
Context.AUDIO_SERVICE
```

i.e

```
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)
```

Comment: Thanks! but I can't use Context in  findViewById(R.id.btnEnableCall).setOnClickListener(..)

Comment: No You can use that in onClick, just because Context is a class name, let me know what is your problem in using that

Comment: Ok, no problem when I use Context.AUDIO_SERVICE, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this is java object oriented  thing :

you geting static variable name called `AUDIO_SERVICE` non static way so instead of use object 
to call static variable use class name to do that.

in your case :

1- object name you calling from it static variable : `appContext`
2- static variable name you getting useing object : `AUDIO_SERVICE`

how to fix :

1- simple call static variable static way without useing object, use Class name like so:

```
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)
```